# CSS float Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, google-chrome

I recently purchased a wordpress theme, and I've bumped into a css problem I can't seem to fix. Unfortunately the theme maker doesn't provide support anymore, so I'm hoping one of you can help me out here :D

If you view this site:

[demo.shakenandstirredweb.com/shaken-grid/](http://demo.shakenandstirredweb.com/shaken-grid/)

in Google Chrome you'll see that the header floats to the left. Nice!

However if you view the site in Firefox you'll see that the header doesn't float to the left, but stays somewhat in the middle. I've been messing around with the id's and classes header, wrap and site-info, but I can't seem to get the Firefox header to float to the left like Chrome.

Chrome

[image: http://d.pr/i/YbPH]

The header floats to the left according to the content in the body.

Firefox

[image: http://d.pr/i/hrTI]

The header remains somewhat in the middle.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

EDIT:
Okay, I've figured out it's the `div` class `wrap`. In Firefox the max width is 'stuck' on `1300px`, while Chrome expands the width automatically.
The weird the thing is, the width of `.wrap` in the stylesheet is set on `1010px`, margin auto.
Anybody know what I should do?

EDIT:
Okay, I think it has something to do with the javascript. I'm guessing this function doesn't work with Firefox:

```
function centerLayout(){
    if( jQuery(window).width() > mobile_width ){
        jQuery('#header .wrap, #footer .wrap, #filtering-nav, .navigation').css('width', jQuery('.isotope').width() - 10);
    }
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: It looks the same for me in chrome and firefox :S This is a responsive theme, are both browsers at the same resolution? Maybe you are watching them in different screens, or with different window sizes...

Comment: Thanks for looking!
I'm using the same resolution, window size and screen to look at the site. I think the logo + navigation also do not float to the left in IE (at least an old version).

Comment: Chrome
http://d.pr/i/YbPH
The header floats to the left according to the content in the body.
Firefox
http://d.pr/i/hrTI
The header remains somewhat in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

add this to your style sheet:

```
#grid {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1050px;
}
```

Comment: the div with the `id="grid"` didnt have any styles applied to it. so it was affecting the divs inside that were centering the content

Comment: i dont know if this was the answer to your question.. when I went to your website in firefox, the content in the middle was all floating to the left (completely different from Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Unfortunately it did not help.. Just to be sure, I want to move the logo + navigation to the left (as it is in Chrome). Not the boxes in the middle.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

try to do it like

for example in this i'm putting 3 columns but to make sure it works in all browsers

```
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3; /*normal att*/
```

do it once with -moz- , another with -webkit- and with none

some property not all browsers understand it so you need to add the kit name that the browser use 
like in the example multi columns not always supported so i needed to add the kit names

the property i wanted to use is "column-count" i write as usual and to make sure it works perfect in all other browsers i add "-kit name-" before the property name

hope i explain it well this time =]

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Could you please be a bit more specific where I should place the code?
Thanks!

Comment: Okay, if I understand you correctly, I should use the -moz- and -webkit- for the float property. I will try it, thanks.

Comment: why is the background colors are different in firefox and chrome ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like

CSS

```
#header {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header > .wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
function centerLayout(){
  if(jQuery(window).width() > mobile_width ){
    newWidth = jQuery('.isotope').width() - 10;
    jQuery('#header .wrap, #footer .wrap, #filtering-nav, .navigation').css('width',newWidth);
  }
}
jQuery(document).ready(centerLayout);
```